# R: How to add indifference curves like these?

Tags: r

I have got a graph like below, except without the red and blue indifference curves (level sets). I know I can use `contour()` but that creates long curves going from edge to edge.

Is there any way I can create such curves? They don't have to follow a function or any data in particular, I just wanna show the general picture.

[image]

Comment: WHat library are you using? ggplot has geom_curve, with some trigonometry you should be able to get the curve to be tangential to the line

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I have been using base R so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with contour

```
sig <- seq(0,0.25,by=.01)
exr <- seq(0,.20,length.out = length(sig))

# define function 
Uf=function(sig,ret,ra=1)ret-0.5*(1/ra)*sig^2
u = outer(sig,exr,function(sd,mr)Uf(sd,mr,ra=0.075))
#image(sig,exr,u)
#contour(sig,exr,u)
contour(sig,exr,u, levels =c(0.04666667, 0.07500000, 0.10333333),col=3,drawlabels = F)
v = outer(sig,exr,function(sd,mr)Uf(sd,mr,ra=0.195))
contour(sig,exr,v, levels =c(0.07333333, 0.09500000, 0.11666667),add = T,col=4,drawlabels = F)
abline(a=0.03,b=0.6666667)
```

[image]

#### Edit

`Uf` is a classical quadratic preference function that depends on risk, return and risk aversion. See more information for example [here](https://www.empiwifo.uni-freiburg.de/lehre-teaching-1/winter-term-10-11/materialien-portfolio-analysis/utility.pdf).
`outer` fist make all possible combination of the supplied vectors `sig` and `exr`, then takes every pair of values and computes the utility with `Uf`. Try `head(u)` or `View(u)`.
`contour` takes all values to plot with the desired levels (indifference curves).
`abline` adds a reference line that you actually have in your plot.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution. Could you please briefly explain the functions? I have been trying to understand what's happening here, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

A handmade solution requiring some fiddling with the position and the curvature:

```
line <- data.frame(x = 0, xend = 0.2, y = 0.03, yend = 0.18)

ggplot(line, aes(x, y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) +
  geom_segment() +
  annotate(
    "curve", 
    x = 0.02 - c(0, 0.005, 0.01),
    y = 0.08 + c(0, 0.01, 0.02), 
    xend = 0.08 - c(0, 0.005, 0.01), 
    yend = 0.14 + c(0, 0.01, 0.02), 
    color = "red", curvature=0.76) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
```